# Clear a Flex ActionScript Dictionary

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Is it possible to clear a Flex `flash.utils.Dictionary`? I have a `Dictionary` that I want to clear (remove all elements).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there is an explicit clear command.

However, you could write your own that would loop through all the keys and run this

```
delete dict[key];
```

Or you can just reassign

```
dict = new  Dictionary()
```

Comment: My goal was reuse the `Dictionary` instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 6):

I *think* this will work, but I'm not 100% sure, as you're modifying the dictionary while iterating over it:

```
function clear(d:Dictionary):void {
  for(var id:* in d) {
    delete d[id];
  }
}
```

However, I generally just create a new Dictionary whenever I need to clear one (though if it's referenced in multiple places then that might not work for you).

Comment: +1 works. tested it by running through twice, it was empty after first run.

Comment: The code above has a defect : 'id' must be of NO type, since a Dictionary can hold any type of object as a key reference and not just a string like dynamic Objects do. The code above would ONLY delete string references!

Comment: I edited the answer to fix the defect.  id is now untyped (*), so it can take on any type and clear all possible keys.  When it was typed as a string, id would only clear string keys; furthermore, no errors are thrown, and id is not null for non-string keys, they are simply skipped during the iteration.  So id must be untyped to iterate over all possible keys.

Answer (score 2):

To remove all the elements in the Dictionary, loop through each key and use the delete keyword

```
function clear(dict:Dictionary):void
{    
  for(var key:Object in dict) 
  {
        delete dict[key];
  }
}
```

If you want to be 100% sure that your deleted keys are garbage collected, you must replace your Dictionary instance with a new Dictionary.

```
dict = new Dictionary();
```

I once had a Dictionary object with 3 million Strings as keys. Those Strings would only be garbage collected when the Dictionary instance itself was.

Answer (score 1):

Not only do you need to make sure the key is of type object or * you need to get the keys first then delete them from the dictionary.  Otherwise you will end up one key left in the dictionary(the last one).

I remember the above code working before but recently that has changed with the last iteration of flash player.

This code will ensure they are all removed including the last one.

```
//Clean up the dictionary
var keys:Array = [];
var key:*;
for ( var key:* in dictionary )
    keys.push( key );
for each ( var key:* in keys )
    delete dictionary[ key ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
dictionary = new Dictionary()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function clear(dict:Dictionary):void {
        var key:*
        for(key in dict) {
            delete dict[key];
        }
    }
```

Use the above function as a utility function and you can use it throughout your code base.